# Symfony doesn't find routes

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have the weirdest problem. Everything was doing just fine and suddenly symfony shows

```
"No route found for "GET /"
```

So i checked router and..none of the routes from my controller were in there.

So i added routing to the **routing.yml** and right now it throws

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_edit_user" as such route does not exist.") in C:\xampp\htdocs\zadanie\src\Cart\Bundle/Resources/views/User/index.html.twig at line 2
```

EVEN THOUGH the action which name is "_edit_user" is right under the one that is being called from routing.

What the hell is happening?

EDIT:
here is what **router:debug** says:

```
_wdt                     ANY    ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}
_profiler_home           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/
_profiler_search         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search
_profiler_search_bar     ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search_bar
_profiler_purge          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/purge
_profiler_info           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/info/{about}
_profiler_import         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/import
_profiler_export         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/export/{token}.txt
_profiler_phpinfo        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/phpinfo
_profiler_search_results ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/search/results
_profiler                ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}
_profiler_router         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/router
_profiler_exception      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception
_profiler_exception_css  ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
_configurator_home       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/
_configurator_step       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/step/{index}
_configurator_final      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/final
blog_show                ANY    ANY    ANY  /
```

and blog_show is the one I added in the routing.yml..

Comment: Can you please post your rounting information?

Comment: Maybe you have tab chars instead of whitespaces in your yml?

Comment: @akluth - i posted the one from router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony2 doesn't auto-map action methods to route names. If you need an action method to be routable, you have to specify that explicitly.

I personally like using annotations for routing, so if you want to do the same, then first add this to **app/config/routing.yml**

```
YourBundle:
    resource: "@YourBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Then add your routing information to your controllers. To use the default controller as an example:

**src/Your/Bundle/Controller/DefaultController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("desired/edit_user/uri", name="_edit_user")
   */
  public function _edit_userAction()
  {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: completely forgot about adding those lines in routing.yml. Thank You!